# Update current timestamp plus x amount of days

Tags: postgresql

If I have a column of `membership_expiry_date TIMESTAMP` (postgresql) and want to get the current expiry date and add 3 days to it, how would I write this query

```
UPDATE users SET membership_expiry_date = ??
```

How do I retrieve the current value and add to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE users 
    SET membership_expiry_date = membership_expiry_date + 3* INTERVAL '1 day'
```

Comment: `3* INTERVAL '1 day'` can be simplified to `interval '3 day'`